# Single Line - PHP for CSV

Tags: php, csv

Emailler.csv:

```
 "email@address1, email@address3, email@address3, ..."
```

**CSVexport.php**:

```
  <?PHP
  $file_handle = fopen("emailler.csv", "r");
  while (!feof($file_handle) ) {      
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
  print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1] . $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";
  }
  fclose($file_handle);
  ?>
```

**Screen**: 
     "email@address1email@address2email@address3..."

Can I print the screen into single line with php?

Comment: Are you wanting to print the CSV onto the screen per line like the file?

Comment: `echo implode(" ", $line_of_text)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm getting what you want,
but what I guess you want, is

```
print_r($line_of_text)
```

This prints all the content of $line_of_text, instead of you needing to call every index on that array.

Comment: it also prints the type of the variable and some additional markup. `print_r` is for debugging only. don't use it to export CSV-data.

Comment: Thank you but output is not.. Screen: "Array ( [0] => email@address.com [1] => zorzi1a3tnjn@goatlantis.info [2] =>.."

Comment: As Basti said, this is only for debugging purpose. Using implode will give the best results for outputting on the screen

Comment: solved: "echo implode(" ", $line_of_text)" @Michael --
Thank you everyone!